# Email Listview contents to outlook via variable email

Tags: sql, vb.net, email, listview, outlook

I have this windows form using vb.net where I call a sql stored procedure and based on the parameter ID entered I get a listview of the stored procedure results.

Now the issue is I can't seem to find any information on how to send these results to an email (to Outlook) where the user can input the email to send to in a textbox on the form or how to reference the results in the listview.

I was thinking of creating a stored procedure with an @email variable where it executes "sp_GetDocs" and the results are sent to the @email variable   in the procedure and I can input that email variable like I did the previous parameter in the form. I am still a beginner to vb.net so I am not sure if this is extra work or if it wont work at all. Can someone point me to the right direction? The vb code is pasted below.

```
 Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form
Dim stlCon As String = "my data source"
Dim sqlCon As SqlConnection
Dim table As New DataTable
Dim PDF As New ListViewItem
Private Sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click
    sqlCon = New SqlConnection(stlCon)

    Using (sqlCon)

        Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand


        sqlComm.Connection = sqlCon


        sqlComm.CommandText = "sp_GetDocs"
        sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOCID", Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text.Trim()))

        sqlCon.Open()
        Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader()

        Using sqlReader
            Dim table As New DataTable
            table.Load(sqlReader)

            ListView1.View = View.Details
            ListView1.GridLines = True
            ListView1.Columns.Add("PDF Name", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
            ListView1.Columns.Add("PDF Description", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
            ListView1.Columns.Add("PDF Location", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Left)

            For Each row In table.Rows

                Dim PDF As New ListViewItem
                PDF.Text = row.Item(0)
                PDF.SubItems.Add(row.item(1))
                PDF.SubItems.Add(row.item(2))

                For i = 1 To table.Columns.Count - 1
                    PDF.SubItems.Add(row(i).ToString(0))
                    PDF.SubItems.Add(row(i).ToString(1))
                    PDF.SubItems.Add(row(i).ToString(2))

                Next
                ListView1.Items.Add(PDF)
            Next
                ListView1.EndUpdate()

        End Using

    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Email_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Email.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

All this does now is execute sp_GetDocs and displays the results in the list view, currently I have a button and a empty textbox on the bottom of my form for this email portion.

Comment: Have you looked into System.Net.Mail? Include it at the top of your page and it exposes all the functionality you need to send an email -- unless I'm misunderstanding what you want to do.

Comment: @Melanie Hi melanie thank you for replying? I am not even sure how to add the email function I have been searching so using the system.Net.Mail would I be able to reference the listview results in the first private sub for the email portion? I tried and it said I had to declare the variables hence I moved some to the public class but I am not sure how to reference the listview results

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! For microsoft 365 I used the format below

Try
            MailBody = ("test")

```
        MailSubject = ("Test")
        MailFrom = New MailAddress(TextBox2.Text)
        MailTo = New MailAddress(TextBox3.Text)

        Mail.From = MailFrom
        Mail.To.Add(MailTo)
        Mail.Subject = MailSubject
        Mail.Body = MailBody



        MailClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com")
        MailClient.Port = 587
        MailClient.EnableSsl = True
        MailClient.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(TextBox2.Text, "Password", "domain")

        MailClient.Send(Mail)
        MsgBox("Email Sent")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error")
    End Try
```